# svn post-commit hook : update only if certain file has changed

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

Okay so I have an SVN repo setup on my server.  I have a post-commit hook setup that updates to a "DEV" folder so that when I commit changes, it automatically pushes to my "DEV" subdomain on my server.

What I need now is an easy way to push it to my "Live" subdomain when I am ready.  The "Live" subdomain is on the same server, and in reality, it would be the same svn update /... command as with the DEV, but to a different path.

I was thinking I could have a specific file in my repo, and maybe I could just change this file, and then make some sort of condition in my post-commit file to also update to my "live" dir if that specific file has changed.

But I don't know how to write that code.  Currently my post-commit file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

svn update /var/www/dev/public
```

I need it to basically do this (but with correct syntax, obviously)

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

svn update /var/www/dev/public
if (pushLive.txt has changed) {
  svn update /var/www/live/public
}
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if this is the most efficient way, and also this the first case will technically work on a file called "pushLive.txt" regardless of dir, so you might wanna play with that or make sure file is unique...

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

for changes in `$LOOK changed $REPOS | awk '{print $1 "=" $2;}'`;
do

  idx=`expr index "$changes" =`;
  directory=${changes:$idx};
  action=${changes:0:$idx-1};

  case "$directory" in
    *pushLive.txt )
      case "$action" in
        "U" )
           svn update /var/www/dev/test/public
           ;;
      esac
      ;;
  esac
done

exit 0
```

Comment: this does not work for me. i got the error : `Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.` i used chmod +x on post-commit and restarted apache. i added the line `touch changedfile.txt` to see if it reaches the loop. it did not get created

Comment: stupid question: did you change the lines of code for your specific setup/file?  Example `*pushLive.txt` should be changed to your `changedfile.txt`.  `svn update /var/www/dev/test/public` should be changed to your path, etc..

Comment: ah i missed to erase the `*`. gonna test it tommorow. thank you.
btw the changedfile.txt is another file next to pushLive.txt just to test if the script gets into the if statement.

Comment: try changing `svn update path/to/dir` to `path/to/svn update path/to/dir`

Comment: ok i failed to use the right path. `svn update /var/www/dev/test/public` was not an svn for me. instead `svn update /var/www/dev/test/public/myApps` was my svn folder. really a stupid error. thanks for your help!

Comment: sweet, glad you figured it out!

Comment: I am using this script as is except I am using the full path to awk and svn (plus of course changing the file name for which I am detecting changes).  I am getting the shell script error "Bad substitution" on the "directory=${changes:$idx};" line.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this through a post-commit hook since an update can take a long time. That means users have to wait around for your update to complete before they get control of their workstations again.

Take a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).

Jenkins is a continuous build server, but you can use it even if you don't have a *build*. In your case, you can use it to watch the Subversion repository for the live domain. When Jenkins detects a commit upon that Subversion URL, it can spawn a *build* process. In your case, it would be updating the files on the live server.

If your server is the same machine running Jenkins, you could easily specify the Jenkins Working directory to be the /var/www/live/public directory. (By default, Jenkins will create the build directory under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<jobname>/workspace`, but there's an option in Jenkins where you can specify it). Then, there's no programming involved at all. This is faster and easier than playing around with a post-commit hook.

By the way, if you take this route, I suggest you create a new update to a clean directory, then rename the directory. Otherwise, as Subversion updates your server, you'll have files from the previous and present Subversion revision at the same time. This could cause problems if someone was on the server while the update is occurring.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion! At first glance, this might be a good long-term solution but for now, I think setting something like this up would be too much trouble.  This is a small server and limited users and very little traffic; specific tool for a specific client sort of thing.  From that perspective, (what I think is) a simple post-commit hook seems ideal

Comment: I mean right now, I just SSH in and go to the "live" dir and do an svn update whenever I'm ready for it to go live, takes literally half a second cuz it's a handful of files and practically 0 traffic and no anticipated growth for it, other than handful of clients who actually use the web interface.  So yeah...just thought updating a specific file in the repo and attaching a post-commit hook seemed best route

Comment: Just to address the point that the committing user will have to wait until the hook returns - you could start the post-commit hook script in the background to avoid this problem.