# svn post commit hook only for milestones

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

We have (want to have) the following setup:

Website + Svn on one Server

and local machines to develop and test the website.

i found post commit hook infos (german): http://www.yourhelpcenter.de/2010/07/svn-nach-einem-commit-automatisch-die-webseite-aktualisieren-post-commit-hook/ which basically update the website on every commit.

and [svn post-commit hook : update only if certain file has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068905/svn-post-commit-hook-update-only-if-certain-file-has-changed) which nearly archives what i am searching for.

we want to commit only to the svn and later merge a stable/polished version aka milestone into a branch which updates the website.

is there a possibility to archive this? is there a way to check if a merge was done? a post-merge hook if you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about committing all of your changes to a development branch and merging only validated changes to the trunk.

Then you can setup your post-commit hook to look only after the trunk so that you update your site only when you merge patches, i.e. when you validate the current state as a stable version.

You can also go the other way around, committing all changes to the trunk (and/or other branches also) and merging wanted changes to a 'stable' branch...

Comment: after merging to a stable branch i would check for a filechange right?
i will give it a try, thx